How can i render all of my render passes at the same time, and different folder? (EEVEE)
If i already have all of this checked, how can i render them automatically on different folders at the same time? (animation, not still frame) on EEVEE?


I was able to do this in the Scene section by adding multiple outputs to any render pass I wanted, and it worked so nicely.

